# How to process data received as an array from req.body

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have tables a and b.
Both data are created at the same time, and b receives the id of a as a FK.

Here, multiple rows can be added to table b at once,
The values ​​received as req.body are as follows.

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "a1": "ccc",
    "a2": "ddd",
    "typeId": [1, 2, 3]
    "count": [60, 100, 5]
}
```

Is there a way to process the data received as an array in the query as shown below?

```
INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count)
  VALUES (0,1,60), (0,2,100), (0,3,5),
```

I've tried the following:

DAO.js

```
const createRecordData = async(userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id,a1,a2)
  VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    [userId, a1, a2]
  );

  const datas = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count)
  VALUES ${typeId.map((tID) =>"(" + "((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())" + "," + tID + "," + count.map((c) => c + ")" ).join(","))}`,
    [typeId, count]
  );
  return data;
};
```

But this returns an error like below:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 101
```

===
I've tried the following.

```
const createRecordData = async(userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id,a1,a2)
  VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    [userId, a1, a2]
  );

const typeAndCount = typeId.map((type, index) => `((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),${type},${count[index]}),`).join("");
  const datas = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count)
  VALUES ${typeAndCount}`,
    [typeId, count]
  );
  return data;
};
```

This will return that error.

```
"typeId.map is not a function"
```

What am I doing wrong? I need help.

Comment: Question, do you want to build a string like `(0,x,x), (0,x,x), (0,x,x),` from the Array?

Comment: yes can you do that?

Comment: Sure I'll try right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that typeId and count arrays always have the same length, you can do like this. Otherwise, some other checks might be involved

```js
const data = {
    "userId": 1,
    "a1": "ccc",
    "a2": "ddd",
    "typeId": [1, 2, 3],
    "count": [60, 100, 5]
};

const processData = (data) => {
  const {typeId, count} = data;
  const typeAndCount = typeId.map((type, index) => `(0,${type},${count[index]}),`).join("");
  return `INSERT INTO data (a_id,typeId,count) VALUES ${typeAndCount}`;
};

console.log(processData(data));
```

Comment: I've tried applying the method you suggested to my code, but I get the error "typeId.map is not a function".
Added code and error message to the body.
I think I'm doing something wrong. I need help.

Comment: I know why! It seems like I need to get it as an array even when there is only one value.
It works fine the way you told me. thank you